# Logback Android - Logs are not being rotated

Tags: android, logback

Here's the logback.xml.

test.log gets created, however, it doesn't get rotated when the file size grows beyond 1KB.

I tested this on the Android emulator as well as on my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone.

I am using logback-android-1.1.1-3.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>test.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>test.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1KB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
    </root>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. This configuration is straight out of http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out myself I had to change two things.

1. I had to extend the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and overridden isTriggeringEvent method.
2. I used the absolute path in filenamepattern.

logback.xml :

```
<configuration>
    <property name="EXT_FILES_DIR" value="${EXT_DIR:-sdcard}"/>  
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${EXT_FILES_DIR}/twapp/logs/twapp.log</file>
        <append>false</append>    

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${EXT_FILES_DIR}/twapp/logs/tw.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>4</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

       <!-- Overridden SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy -->
        <triggeringPolicy class="com.twapp.util.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YY:HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
    </root>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And Extended SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy class:

```
public class SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E> extends ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E>
{

    @Override    
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(final File activeFile, final E event)
    {
        return (activeFile.length() >= FileSize.valueOf(getMaxFileSize()).getSize());  
    }
}
```